# How to drag a label and drop on UIToolbarItem in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, drag-and-drop, uilabel, uitoolbar

I am facing problem to drag and drop UILabel .

How to drag label(Move This) and drop on any one of UIToolBar item (i.e., 1 or 2 or 3 ...) that button title should change as label text.

[Check image for this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQSGc.png)

Comment: Have you tried [`UIPanGestureRecognizer`](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/11/draggable-buttons-labels/) with your label?

Comment: @Amar Yes i used UIPanGestureRecognizer

Answer (score 1):

Use custom button as a label and then use this code as :

```
     UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTouch:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    button.tag = -1;
button.titleLabel.text = @"Move this";
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTouch:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
        [self.view addSubview:button];
```

Then you may move the buttol wherever you want, by responding to the UIControlEventTouchDragInside event, e.g.:

```
- (IBAction) btnTouch:(id) sender withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{
    CGPoint point = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    UIControl *control = sender;
    control.center = point;

    //Here use this to check when intersects and check if the frame of the item you are moving intersects with the frame from on of your subviews
    for (UIView *anotherBtn in self.view.subviews) {

        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(control.frame, anotherBtn.frame)) {
            // Do something
            [anotherBtn setTitle:control.titleLabel.text];
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

UIBarButtonItem has it's own title, you can't drag label on it