# How to drag and drop a UILabel from one view to another?

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop

I am trying to make an iOS app in which there are tabs (on the main view) on top which when touched displays a popover. The popover contains a list of names that the user can drag and drop to the main view. How could you implement this? I have already found some answers on how to drag and drop when you are on the same view:

[How to drag a label and drop on UIToolbarItem in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792771/how-to-drag-a-label-and-drop-on-uitoolbaritem-in-iphone)

However, what is the best way to do it when you are doing this on two different views? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would think you want to have a controller containing the two other view controllers for the views you are trying to drag between. On press you might detect where it is in view one, passing this object via a delegate to the master view controller. On touch up you could detect if it is within view two and pass all your details to that  view controllers delegate. Just thinking out loud, so take it as you wish. :).